# Have I reached the Refactoring Tipping Point?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, refactoring

I have a form whose constructor I've overloaded to pass in an enumerated type and a `List<int>`.

Now I realize I also need to pass in another `int` (that doesn't belong in the `List<int>`).

At what point is it considered "good form" (no pun intended) to regroup and refactor and encapsulate all those parameters into a class and pass that?

Or is there a better way (that doesn't require Houdini-esque sleight of hand)?

Comment: 5 parameters - always 5 parameters. That's an absolutely cast-in-stone rule. I'm surprised it'll compile with more :-) Seriously though, it depends on the function, the parameters and the nature of what you're passing.

Comment: For readers whose primary language may not be english, pm_2 is being humorous when he says 5 parameters is the "cast-in-stone rule."  The actual answer he is giving is that "it depends on the function, etc."  I voted up because it made me chuckle, and then realized that some folks might get confused.

Answer (score 2):

You could expose the fields as public properties and use the following syntax:

```
var myinstance = new MyType
{
    Prop1 = val1,
    Prop2 = val2,
    Prop3 = val3
};
```

This saves you needing to alter the constructor time after time. I regards to your "when is it best to..." question, I personally go with if I expect it to grow beyond 2 or three (now or in the future) I will create a parameters class. This may be open to quite a bit of debate though!

Comment: Note that if you take this approach, you only have to alter existing code if the new parameters/properties are required in that context.

Answer (score 2):

Things to consider before you up and make a new object for this function

How often are you using this function?
Do you have duplicate code? Will creating this class help remove duplicate code?
Does it increase efficiency (code performance and maintenance)?
Which is faster? Customers don't care about a lot of this.

Adding another constructor with more parameters isn't going against any practice, though if you have a crap load of constructors that call themselves in weird orders I'd suggest rethinking it...

If your application requires it, add it. Having:

```
public FormConstructor(List<int> someInts, MyEnumThing anEnumYay, int anotherInt)
```

Isn't bad - except for my naming....

My oppinion? I'd add the Int if I didn't see any potential gains for creating a class.

Creating a class "solely because" you don't want many input parameters is the **wrong** reason to create said class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it all depends on how much refactoring you'll have to do elsewhere as a result of the change. If you push everything into the new class, will other parts of the application stop working as a result? How many bugs might this introduce? IMO three or four parameters is fine, but once I start pushing 5 or more into the signature, I tend to create a class to handle the job.

Quotes and such can become a factor, because, if you have to get the job done in an hour, but it will take you three to create a class, update other bits of code, and test, you might just have to add a new parameter and revisit it later.

Comment: An hour? It takes me an hour to put my pants on.